# Membership Provider based on PhPbb database

Tags: c#, forms-authentication, phpbb

I am just wondering how to go about implementing a forms Membership provider based off of a PhPbb forum database. I have looked at simply hashing the password using a function port of 'phpbb_hash' and comparing it to the database values, however I can't seem to grasp the login system as the hashes I was getting were not the same as those in the database.

Can someone tell me how to authenticate a users credentials against a PhPbb database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a project here on CodePlex, but it seems abandoned: http://phpbbproviders.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen this [thread with an authentication provider](http://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=71&t=1771165)? It looks like a good start to at least fix your authentication problem, as it seems to have the hashing problem down.

Comment: Yeah I have, but may I ask what is the remote hash? is it a field in the phpbb users table? if so, which? thanks for pointing out this solution to me =)